# How to get the value of a style that gives data to an div? [MyShop E-commerce]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, e-commerce

I'm using MyShop(www.myshop.com) for my shop. But they are using a kind of programming which I never saw before.

An example of outputting the total price output in the basket.html script:

```
<span style="myshop-value:price-total-formatted;white-space:nowrap;"></span>
```

output:

€ 100,00

So this Span without any data inside it's tag output the price of the total product that has been in the basket. So i'm guessing they are using a CSS stylesheet to get get the data from, which is new for me to be honest.

I want to make a JavaScript function that output a message that depends on the price.

So when the product is under € 25 There must output a message that says example "You'll have free shipping"

and when de product is over € 25 a message must come and say "You'll have to pay for shipping".

See here the Js script for that function:

```
<div id="price"></div>

<p id="shipping"></p>

<script>
    var price = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;

    if (price < 24.99) {
        document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "You'll have free shipping";
    }

    if (price > 25) {
        document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "You'll have to pay for shipping";
    }
</script>
```

The problem is when I fill the price div with a number the JS just works. But whenever I put the Span inside with the Style in it then the div couldn't find the data I guess.

I never saw this kind or programming, I've googled but I just couldn't find something(or I just googled wrong). A solution will be great, but a explanation about this way of programming would also be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2mdmz3bq/

```
var innerHtml = $('#theLabel').html();
var intVal = parseInt(innerHtml.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

You'll need a way to find the span in javascript so i added an id attribute. After we get the inner html we need to get rid of the euro/dollar sign and convert the resulted string to an integer.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved this problem and a lot more I have using this E-Commerce!!!

Comment: Unfortunately it only get the numbers before the , out. So 100,99 will output 100. Do you know the way to get the whole price?

Comment: Change the regex in `innerHtml.match()` to `/\d+(,\d\d)?/`. This would match 1 or more digits, and then optionally a comma followed by two digits. You may need to replace the `,` with a `.` in the resultant number to make it parse properly as a decimal number, though. You also need to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: Done :) http://jsfiddle.net/2mdmz3bq/1/
It was needed a different regex and parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: I'm really grateful, I really am. But I still have one problem, it only get the decimals when a dot is used. When a comma is used only the first numbers before the comma will show. I'm using numbers with comma decimals for my website. I thought perhaps if I change the . into a , then it will do it's thing. But it don't work like that I've learned. I've googled to see how the regex work.. But it's more complicated then I thought.. I've tried a lot of things but none work.

Comment: Actually, the RegEx should work like that. I think the problem is at the `parseFloat()` part, which can only accept float numbers using a `.` as the decimal separator. As I said earlier, you will need to replace the `,` with a `.` in the resultant parsed number. For example, you can try using `parseFloat(innerHtml.match(/\d+(\,\d\d)?/)[0].replace(',', '.;))`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should say `parseFloat(innerHtml.match(/\d+(\,\d\d)?/)[0].replace(',', '.'))`